# How to make a Multicast Delegates in Blueprint?

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints, delegates

**I used the Set Timer by Event, but I could not use the delegate in more than one event:**

[image]

**I've been researching about and it's possible, but I've only found results in c ++:**

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates/index.html

**My code:**

[image]

This is not at all functional. I'm using the same function twice.

I could call the "second" event after the execution of the "first" event, but I would like to know a way (if any) to use the delegate in more than one event.

Comment: Multicast delegates are available only in C

Comment: So the best alternative would be what I did, or call the "second" event after the execution of "first" event?

Comment: "Best alternative" is obviously to use C++, but if you are constrained with Blueprints, it is better to call the second event rather than having 2 timers. (Also it is not documented that Timers will fire in the order you set them, and if they do for now, it could be changed in future).

Comment: Is there any way to convert a project made through blueprints, to code in c ++?

Comment: Sure, right click on "ContentBrowser" (Typical at bottom part of the editor) window and You will see the "New C++ Class" option.